# Грохнуть план по определенному запросу

Tags: sql-server

Есть `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`, который на вход может принять конкретный хендл плана.

Подскажите, вот у меня есть какой-то запрос, а как я могу узнать хендл плана, который ему соответствует, что бы подчистить план только по нему?

Answer (score 2):

Сначала нужно найти хэндл плана в кэше:

```
SELECT
    text,
    cp.objtype,
    cp.usecounts,
    text,
    OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid) AS ProcName,
    DB_NAME(st.dbid) AS DatabaseName,
    cp.plan_handle
FROM        sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) AS st;
```

Можно добавить секцию WHERE и поискать по тексту запроса.
Полученный хэндл вставляем в инструкцию:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (0x050004005A6C1A7CC05ECC6DE401000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000);
```

И запускаем, план удален из кэша.